# add extra property in ui-route when state changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two routes in ui-router, one will only exec a put, and if ok, I transition it to another, said this, the second, can be retrieve from this previos one or directly. I need a way to let the controller knows if I'm coming from the first route or not. So far I have this that should work but doesn't.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('one', {
            //info omitted for convenience
            resolve: {
                doSomething : function(getSomething) {
                    return getSomething();
                }
            }
        })
        .state('two', {
            //info omitted for convenience
            resolve: {
                collectionTasks: function($http, $state) {
                    $http.put('/url/', {blabla})
                    .then(function(){
                       $state.transitionTo('one', null, {notify: true});
                    }) 
                }
            }

        });



 //in my controller...

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log(fromState) ; //never gets fires the first time even if notify is set on true
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the $rootScope.on... in app.run(function ($rootScope){  `here`}) ?

Comment: doesnt make any difference, i need to trigger stuff in the controller, im unlike to create a event to spread another event, or i'm missing something